# Clock - label and arrows

Tags: graphics, labeling

I have 12 circles.  How every single circle sign (from 1 to 12). I know only how to sign with my range `{a, 0, 2 π - π/6, π/6}`, but I need to have numbers 1-12.

Maybe any ideas how I can make 3 arrows?

```
Graphics[Table[{ColorData["TemperatureMap", 1 - a/(2 π - π/6)], 
   Disk[{Cos[a + π/2], Sin[a + π/2]}, 0.1], 
   Text[Style[a, Black], {Cos[a + π/2], Sin[a + π/2]}]}, {a, 0, 2 π - π/6, π/6}]]
```

Comment: Look up `Text[]` for adding labels.

Comment: Okay, I eddited, but how to label as 1-12 not pi etc.?

Comment: Maybe try using `Table[..., {a, 1, 12}]` instead and compute the angle as `(2 Pi/12) a`. Or by all means, divide the angle by `Pi/6` to get the number. Whatever you think is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{h, m, s} = {1, 24, 52};
ah = π/2 - 2 π h/12 - (2 π) m/720;
am = π/2 - 2 π m/60;
as = π/2 - 2 π Floor[s]/60;

Graphics[ {Table[{ ColorData["TemperatureMap", 1 - a/(2 π - π/6)], 
       Disk[{Cos[a + π/2], Sin[a + π/2]}, 0.1], 
       Text[Style[12 - 6 a /Pi, Black], {Cos[a + π/2], Sin[a + π/2]}]}, 
       {a, 0, 2 π - π/6, π/6}], ,
    Thick, Black, Arrowheads[Large], 
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, .7 {Cos[ah], Sin[ah]}}], Arrow[{{0, 0}, .95 {Cos[am], Sin[am]}}], 
    GrayLevel[.3], Line[{{0, 0}, 0.8 {Cos[as], Sin[as]}}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The coordinates for the hour, minute and second arrows from:[Texture >> Applications >> Dynamic Clock Box](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Texture.html)